# Can't extract HTML source of a webpage (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Page source code: view-source:https://www.myhome.ie/residential/dublin/property-for-sale

```
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.myhome.ie/residential/dublin/property-for-sale"
html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

# paging = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"PropertyInfoStrip ng-star-inserted"})
```

I need to get the html of the source so I can scrape of the div classes but with bs4 its only showing the JS scripts and I can't extract anything of the HTML? What am I doing wrong. I can see the HTML when going through my browsers inspect element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can make Ajax request to get the data in Json format:

```
import json
import requests


params = {
    "ApiKey": "5f4bc74f-8d9a-41cb-ab85-a1b7cfc86622",
    "CorrelationId": "e4e14c46-53e6-463f-9bdc-f67785bd4915",
    "SessionId": None,
    "RequestTypeId": 2,
    "RequestVerb": "POST",
    "Endpoint": "https://api.myhome.ie/search",
    "Page": 1,
    "PageSize": 20,
    "SortColumn": 2,
    "SortDirection": 2,
    "SearchRequest": {
        "IsBackendSearch": False,
        "SkipSearchIndex": False,
        "IsGroupPrivateSearch": False,
        "IsSaleAgreed": False,
        "IsSold": False,
        "IsAuction": False,
        "IsBoundsSearch": False,
        "UseFreeTextSearchForKeywords": False,
        "SearchContent": False,
        "PropertyIds": [],
        "GroupIds": [],
        "ChannelIds": [1],
        "PropertyTypeIds": [],
        "PropertyClassIds": [1],
        "PropertyStatusIds": [2, 12],
        "SaleTypeIds": [],
        "FeatureTypeIds": [],
        "RegionId": 1265,
        "LocalityIds": [],
        "LocalityNames": [],
        "NegotiatorIds": [],
        "SolicitorIds": [],
        "BuyerSolicitorIds": [],
        "VendorSolicitorIds": [],
        "TransferedByUserIds": [],
        "RowStatusIds": [2],
        "EnergyRatings": [],
        "Polygons": [],
        "Destinations": [],
        "Tags": [],
        "PrivateTags": [],
        "PreSixtyThree": False,
        "IsActive": True,
        "HasPhotos": False,
        "PriceFrequency": "Monthly",
    },
}

url = "https://api.myhome.ie/search"

params["Page"] = 1  # <--- change to desired page
data = requests.post(url, json=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some results to screen
for result in data["SearchResults"]:
    print("{:<30} {}".format(result["PropertyType"], result["DisplayAddress"]))
```

Prints:

```
Semi-Detached House            248 Swords Road, Whitehall, Dublin 9, D09 K8W7
Apartment                      24 Mountfield Park, Malahide,   County Dublin
Semi-Detached House            26 Griffeen Glen Boulevard, Lucan, Co. Dublin
Semi-Detached House            4 Bedroom Home at Skylark, St. Marnock's Bay, Portmarnock, Dublin
Terraced House                 250 Laraghcon, Lucan, Co. Dublin
Bungalow                       1 Castleland Park View, Balbriggan, County Dublin
Semi-Detached House            657 Whitechurch Road, Taylors Lane, Rathfarnham, Dublin 14
Terraced House                 22 Reuben Avenue, Rialto, Dublin 8
Semi-Detached House            Merrion Lodge, 135 Mount Merrion Avenue, Blackrock, Co. Dublin
Terraced House                 74 Seapark Drive, Clontarf, Dublin 3
Terraced House                 5 O'Daly Road, Drumcondra, Dublin 9
Detached House                 Churchtown House, Weston Park, Dublin 14, Dublin
Detached House                 St. Kevins, 17 Rathfarnham Park, D14, Dublin 14, Dublin
Terraced House                 The Terrace, Foxrock, Dublin 18
Terraced House                 7 Whately Place, Kilmacud Road Upper, Stillorgan, Co. Dublin
Detached House                 The Cottage, Dublin Road, Oldtown, County Dublin
Semi-Detached House            31 Gleann Na Smol, Oldbawn, Dublin 24
Terraced House                 218 Castlecurragh Heath, Mulhuddart, Dublin 15
Semi-Detached House            19 Woodside, Dodder Park Road, Rathfarnham, Dublin 14
Apartment                      Apartment, 46 Slade Castle Court, Saggart, Co. Dublin
```