# Key Error in web scraping from POST Request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
import json, csv
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
"ApiKey": "5f4bc74f-8d9a-41cb-ab85-a1b7cfc86622",
"CorrelationId": "e4e14c46-53e6-463f-9bdc-f67785bd4915",
"SessionId": None,
"RequestTypeId": 2,
"RequestVerb": "POST",
"Endpoint": "https://api.myhome.ie/search",

*AND MORE. Read note at bottom*
}

url = "https://api.myhome.ie/search"


for x in range(2):

    params["Page"] = x  # <--- change to desired page
    data = requests.post(url, json=params).json()

    with open('data.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:

        f.write("Property Type | Property Status | Display Address | Price \n")

        for result in data["SearchResults"]:
            results = "{} | {} | {} | {} | {}".format(result["PropertyType"], result["PriceAsString"], result["BedsString"], result["PropertyStatus"], result["DisplayAddress"])

            fwriter = csv.writer(f,delimiter = '|')
            fwriter.writerow(result)
```

From the URL at https://www.myhome.ie/residential/dublin/property-for-sale, why does the parameter PriceAsString keep throwing a key error? It does exist, everything else is working fine besides that

NOTE: I had to remove the parameters else it wasn't letting me post this question because of too much code. Left the first 5

EDIT: can get the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721391/10976096) if you want to try to recreate

Comment: Do you need to use requests, I think this could be done in a better way with a web scrapping tool such as scrapy, beatifulsoup or selenium.

Comment: I tried using bs4 before but since the content was loaded dynamically I couldn't access the HTML

Comment: It’s scraping not scrapping. Similarly scrape, scraped, scraper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because the `PriceAsString` is *not* in every result.

One way of dealing with this would be with a `try except` block, for example:

```
import requests

params = {
    "ApiKey": "5f4bc74f-8d9a-41cb-ab85-a1b7cfc86622",
    "CorrelationId": "e4e14c46-53e6-463f-9bdc-f67785bd4915",
    "SessionId": None,
    "RequestTypeId": 2,
    "RequestVerb": "POST",
    "Endpoint": "https://api.myhome.ie/search",
    "Page": 1,
    "PageSize": 20,
    "SortColumn": 2,
    "SortDirection": 2,
    "SearchRequest": {
        "IsBackendSearch": False,
        "SkipSearchIndex": False,
        "IsGroupPrivateSearch": False,
        "IsSaleAgreed": False,
        "IsSold": False,
        "IsAuction": False,
        "IsBoundsSearch": False,
        "UseFreeTextSearchForKeywords": False,
        "SearchContent": False,
        "PropertyIds": [],
        "GroupIds": [],
        "ChannelIds": [1],
        "PropertyTypeIds": [],
        "PropertyClassIds": [1],
        "PropertyStatusIds": [2, 12],
        "SaleTypeIds": [],
        "FeatureTypeIds": [],
        "RegionId": 1265,
        "LocalityIds": [],
        "LocalityNames": [],
        "NegotiatorIds": [],
        "SolicitorIds": [],
        "BuyerSolicitorIds": [],
        "VendorSolicitorIds": [],
        "TransferedByUserIds": [],
        "RowStatusIds": [2],
        "EnergyRatings": [],
        "Polygons": [],
        "Destinations": [],
        "Tags": [],
        "PrivateTags": [],
        "PreSixtyThree": False,
        "IsActive": True,
        "HasPhotos": False,
        "PriceFrequency": "Monthly",
    },
}

for x in range(2):
    params["Page"] = x  # <--- change to desired page
    data = requests.post("https://api.myhome.ie/search", json=params).json()
    for result in data["SearchResults"]:
        try:
            results = "{} | {} | {} | {} | {}".format(
                result["PropertyType"], result["PriceAsString"],
                result["BedsString"], result["PropertyStatus"],
                result["DisplayAddress"],
            )
            print(results)
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Output:

```
Apartment | €225,000 | 1 bed | ForSale | 1A Rathborne Avenue, Ashtown, Dublin 15
Apartment | POA | 3 beds | ForSale | 3 Bedroom Apartment - 143 Merrion Road, Dublin 4
Semi-Detached House | €825,000 | 4 beds | ForSale | 10 Ashdale Park, Terenure,   Dublin 6W
Detached House | €1,300,000 | 4 beds | ForSale | 7 Castleknock Green, Castleknock,   Dublin 15
Terraced House | €2,500,000 | 5 beds | ForSale | 2 Avoca Terrace, Avoca Road, Blackrock, Co. Dublin
Terraced House | €375,000 | 3 beds | ForSale | 3 Whitechurch Park, Ballyboden, Rathfarnham, Dublin 16, D16 W2V9
Apartment | POA | 2 beds | ForSale | 2 Bedroom Apartment -143 Merrion Road, Dublin 4
Detached House | €720,000 | 4 beds | ForSale | Kettles Lane, Marshallstown, Swords, County Dublin
Terraced House | €225,000 | 2 beds | ForSale | 348 Castlecurragh Heath, Mulhuddart, Dublin 15
Semi-Detached House | €395,000 | 4 beds | ForSale | 78 Lambourn Park, Clonsilla, Dublin 15
Semi-Detached House | €1,050,000 | 5 beds | ForSale | 20 Shandon Park, Monkstown, Co. Dublin

and so on ...
```

Comment: Oh I see thanks! I was assuming every listing would have a price on that website, should've gone through it in more detail. Ill do the try except else just remove the priceasstring parameter in the except condition

Comment: Hey, there are some parameters which return tuples like ```BrochureMap``` and ```Photos```. Would you happen to know how I could use python fstrings to properly return/print these in my csv file? It current outputs an error and doesn't even run

Comment: I guess I do but I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Yeah i did that, was facing another issue too with your try/except method so asked if theres a better way